# Running through SQL select statements on oracle apex. One returning "SQL command not properly ended" and I don't know why

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle-apex

I have tables filled with data on Oracle APEX, and I have a task to write and then run select statements on them.

The task I have a problem with is selecting a list of customers which live at a postcode with a specified beginning, "FB1" or "FB2".  The postcode must have "FB1" or "FB2" at the start, but is followed by a space, then another 3 unspecified letters.  Eg "FB1 4X3", "FB2 O9H".

Here's the statement I wrote:

```
select F_NAME, L_NAME, POSTCODE
    from CUSTOMER
    where POSTCODE like 'FB1%', 'FB2%';
```

When I run it in APEX it returns "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended".  I have very similar statements that work fine, so can anyone see this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LIKE` can only have one value. You probably want this instead:

```
select F_NAME, L_NAME, POSTCODE
from CUSTOMER
where POSTCODE like 'FB1%' OR POSTCODE like 'FB2%';
```